# Disable TeXstudio annoying error popup on build

Tags: errors, texstudio

I installed TeXstudio to check it but i'd like to disable error popup since it's totally counterproductive and it would be better if errors were displayed only in logs.

Here's the mentioned error popup:
[image]

Thank you so much.

Comment: EDIT: error popup is repeated 3 times. Very annoying also.

Comment: that error is telling you it can not start pdflatex so there would be no pdftex log with any errors.  You need to fix your installation so that pdftex is installed and texstudio can find it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the problem is specifically THE POPUP dialog. It is displayed for any type of error. I wish it to be displayed on texstudio console instead. This error was manually caused by to so I can show this popup error that I want to disable.

Comment: As already pointed out in Github in response to your same query this is not a compilation error and would therefore have nothing to do with the logs. It is a problem with the way you have configured TexStudio and LaTex - and you have not told us how you did that.